# CSS formatting disappearing after removal of webkit implemented scrollbar in external stylesheet

Tags: html, css

I am having a strange problem. I have an external style sheet in which I have used a webkit scroll bar. Now, I don't want to use it anymore but when I remove the three line code which implements the custom scrollbar, the whole CSS formatting disappears from all the pages using the stylesheet.

Webpage with the webkit code.

[image]

Webpage after removing the webkit code.

[image]

Here is the CSS code:

```
<style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {background-color:#70AFB4; height:auto;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {background-color:#70AFB4; height:10px !important;}
::-webkit-scrollbar {height:7px; width:7px; background-color:#E7E6E1;}

body{
background: #F6F6F6;
font-family: Ubuntu,Georgia;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 150%;
color: #333;    }

h1{
color:#0E0B06;
font-weight:normal;
font-size:40px;
margin-bottom:0px; }

h2{
color:#0E0B06;
font-size:15px;
font-weight:normal;
margin-bottom:0px; }

a{
color:#0E0B06;
padding:1px 2px;
background:#70AFB4;
text-decoration: none; }

a.default {
background:none; }

a:hover{
color:#0E0B06;
background:none; }


.wrapper {
width: 800px margin:auto; }

.header {
margin: 30px 50px 75px 400px; 
width: 400px }

.indexer {
width: 150px;
float: left;
margin: 40px 100px 75px 150px; }

.poster {
width: 700px;
margin: 70px 50px 75px 400px;
padding-bottom: 30px; }
```

The webkit code in question:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {background-color:#70AFB4; height:auto;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {background-color:#70AFB4; height:10px !important;}
::-webkit-scrollbar {height:7px; width:7px; background-color:#E7E6E1;}
```

Comment: @DeepakKamat I'm sorry, I don't have one. I have not uploaded the site nor do I have the tools to do so right now.

Comment: @K_K PLease see my answer. Remove the first line. It is invalid. Now it should work. Let me know if it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### If that's the external stylesheet with the first line:

```
<style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Then it is invalid. This way, the rules for `body` won't be taken.

The `<style>` tag is not required in external CSS files, doing so will result in an error, which prevents the first rule not to get executed.

Removing the `<style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">` from your CSS file will fix it.

Comment: Do you want me to completely remove the style tag?

Comment: YES, if it is a `.css` file! :)

Comment: Ohh, yes, Didn't noticed that you are using <style> tags in an external stylesheet. Just remove the <style> tags and it will all work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the improvement @DeepakKamat.

Comment: You're welcome and that's how we make this community a better place. Keep doing the good work. @PraveenKumar